# Remove sub string between special indicators in C

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to obfuscate some information indicated between `URL='` and `'` from a string in C. And I need to implement a help function for that. For example, the given string is

```
User 'Steve K.' has recently reviewed URL='https://blabla123' and commented ....
```

The result needs to be:

```
User 'Steve K.' has recently reviewed URL='x' and commented ....
```

I have tried this but it does not work as expected:

```
    const char *helper(char *inStr) {
    char *first_position_ptr = strchr(inStr, 'URL=\'');
    char *last_position_ptr = strrchr(inStr, '\'');

    memmove(first_position_ptr+1, last_position_ptr, strlen(last_position_ptr)+1);

    return input;

}

int main() {
    char str[] = "'Steve K.' has recently reviewed URL='https://blabla123' and commented ....
";
    helper(str);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

but the when I compile I realized I can't use `strrch` in this way and the result is wrong

```
JeffB:$ gcc test.c -o test
test.c: In function ‘helper’:
test.c:7:46: warning: character constant too long for its type
     char *first_position_ptr = strchr(inStr, 'URL=\'');
                                              ^
JeffB:$ ./test 
'' and commented ....
```

Could anyone show me some more efficient way or correct way of doing it please?

Comment: And where is there the word  SSID in the source string?

Comment: where is function: `proc()`?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Sorry. I made some typos. Now it should be correct

Comment: @user3629249 Sorry. I made some typos. Now it should be correct

Comment: `strchr(inStr, 'URL=\'');`?? Better `strchr (first_position_ptr + 1, '\'');` than `strrchr(inStr, '\'');` (it protects against further single-quotes in the remainder of your input line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char *first_position_ptr = strchr(inStr, 'SSID=\'');
```

`SSID` is string, not a character. The declaration of `strchr` need second argument as integer type.

```
char *strchr(const char *s, int c);
```

If you want to find a word in string, you can use `strstr` function:

```
char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle);
```

The  strstr() function finds the first occurrence of the substring `needle` in the string `haystack`. So, your code can change to:

```
char *first_position_ptr = strstr(inStr, "SSID=\'");
```